# Modal does not appear

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog

I'm using the react-native-modal component, but the modal does seem to display on button click, used the same example as in the "A complete example section" :

When isVisible is changed to visible it works fine:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import Modala from "react-native-modal";

export default class ModalTester extends Component {

state = {
   isModalVisible: false
};

_toggleModal = () =>
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._toggleModal}>
                <Text>Show Modal</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Modala isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <Text>Hello!</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._toggleModal}>
                        <Text>Hide me!</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </Modala>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Expected: 
 I expect the modal to display on click

Comment: Hi Akshay, I tested your code on expo snack, added react-native-modal,  and it works fine. Which version of the library are you using?

Comment: I am using 7.0.2 the latest version